# Unique constraint that allows zero values (not null) in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am facing the following problem.

I have a table with this column:

```
`responsible_id` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
```

From some reasons that have to do with the project, I cannot change this definition (NULL as default is not an option in this project).

I need to have this column UNIQUE, unless the value is 0.
Of course, I can do a check before I do `INSERT`/`UPDATE` from my php code, but constraints exist exactly to avoid this bad practice...

Any idea how to do it?

Comment: Sounds like bad design. use NULL as a placeholder for whatever default value you need

Comment: @Martin, you are totally right. But unfortunately, like it happens many times in our world, some of the design is already given and I cannot change it.

Answer (score 1):

Existing:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tablename (
    ...
    `responsible_id` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    ... );
```

Addition:

```sql
ALTER TABLE tablename 
    ADD COLUMN responsible_id_null VARCHAR(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci
        GENERATED ALWAYS AS (NULLIF(responsible_id, '0')) /* STORED / VIRTUAL */,
    ADD UNIQUE INDEX idx_responsible_id_null (responsible_id_null);
```

PS. Remember, that this may cause problems - for example, if somewhere `SELECT *` is used... or `INSERT` without columns list...

---

> Could you edit and explain what's going on here, thanks :-) – Martin

I simply add generated column where `'0'` value is replaced with `NULL` value, and create unique index by this column (which will forbid duplicates but ignore/allow NULLs in generated column, i.e. forbid duplicates in source column but ignore/allow `'0'` in it).

Comment: Could you edit and explain what's going on here, thanks `:-)`

Comment: Nice solution, thanks! Although I thought more of using in some way the condition inside the constraint, exactly in order to avoid the possible problems you mention...

Comment: Some of us are not as smart as you `:-p`.

Comment: does the generated column copy the non-0 value of the source column?

Comment: @Martin SQL is highly self-documented language. Especially in such simple cases.

Comment: What happens if the coder SELECT's `responsible_id` instead of `responsible_id_null` ? Is there any way of "hiding" the original column?

Comment: @Martin *does the generated column copy the non-0 value of the source column?* [NULLIF() fnction](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flow-control-functions.html#function_nullif). *What happens if the coder requests responsible_id instead of responsible_id_null ?* The coder may not be aware of the existence of this field at all. And he must not use it.